# What is the best option to play a sound effect /music with javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, audio

I've seen and tried several things with AudioCLip, MediaPlayer and more, but nothing really worked. Also, I have no idea how the URL or URI system works. There again I've seen many things but don't know which are actually right.

This is the Code I used in my last try:

```
public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Initialising path of the media file, replace this with your file path
        //File is in the same project with the following path:
        String path = "file:src/SoundTest/Megalovania.mp3";
        File file = new File(path);

        //Instantiating Media class
        if(file.exists()) {
            Media media = new Media(file.getPath());
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        } else{
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }

        //Instantiating MediaPlayer class


        //by setting this property to true, the audio will be played

        primaryStage.setTitle("Playing Audio");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Can someone tell me if this worked if the URL was right? And if not, what else is wrong?

Comment: "_...but nothing really worked_". What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Slaw mostly I think something was wrong with the URL or something or it would throw an IllegalAccesorError or something. And sometimes it just doesn't play sound. No Errors but also no sound.

Comment: If your audio file is a _resource_, then you should be using `getClass().getResource(...).toExternalForm()` to get the source used with `new Media(...)`.

Comment: I'd recommend the library https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue as an alternative, but it won't work either if you haven't figured out how to get a resource. But the documentation for it does have a "Usage" example (with URL) of how to get a resource (where the sound file is in the same directory as the class that reads the file). That might be helpful. Or a tutorial like the following: http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/java/system/java-resource-loading-explained-absolute-and-relative-names-difference-between-classloader-and-class-resource-loading

Comment: @Slaw how do I know what exactly a resource is?

Comment: A resource is a "file" that is on the classpath/modulepath. They end up getting deployed with the application, typically bundled inside the JAR file. Most build tools, such as _Maven_ or _Gradle_, by default require a certain directory structure for your project that separates source files from resource files; for example, `*.java` files go in `src/main/java` and all other files go in `src/main/resources`. If you're just using your IDE, then you should look up how it handles resource files (e.g. by marking a directory as a "resources root").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, but only if you have something else like a Scene, otherwise the code will stop early. Not sure if an empty stage works.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class AudioTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String musicFile = "Megalovania.mp3";     // For example

        Media sound = null;
        try {
            sound = new Media(getClass().getResource(musicFile).toURI().toString());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
        mediaPlayer.play();

    }
}
```

It was the path/resource all along. I figured it out thanks to my teacher now.